Through the ssh connection, only the "helm list" command has an error "Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable."
SSH is connected to the remote server from the local server to open the command window and enter in the order of 1) helm repo update → 2) helm list as a Python script.
The output of 1) is normally returned, but the output of 2) is returned as None.
I tried connecting ssh to the remote server through moboxterm in my local pc, and then entered 1) 2), it is confirmed that they are output normally. (not None)
The SSH connection is normal, but only the command of 2) does not seem to be performed properly.
When 2) is performed, an error log called "Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable" appears.
I have confirmed that the ssh connection is normal, and it is normal to perform the problematic command manually. There is a problem only when running with python script.
Here is code and log below.
1. lib/ssh.py
class SSH:

def __init__(self, cfg: dict, verbose=False) -> None:
    self._host = cfg.get("host")
    self._port = cfg.get("port")
    self._username = cfg.get("username")
    self._password = cfg.get("password")
    if not all([self._host, self._port, self._username, self._password]):
        raise ValueError(
            f"URL must include a value for the host[{self._host}],port[{self._port}],username[{self._username}],password[{self._password}] to use. None is not allowed!!"
        )
    self._client = None
    info(f"init done [cfg={cfg}]" if verbose else "init done")

### public
def connect(self):
    if self._client is None:
        self._client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self._client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self._client.connect(
            hostname=self._host,
            port=self._port,
            username=self._username,
            password=self._password,
        )
        _transport = self._client.get_transport()
        _transport.set_keepalive(60)
        info("connected!")


def disconnect(self):
    self._client = self._client.close() if not self._client is None else None
    info("disconnected!")


def command(self, cmd: str, wait_for=None, timeout=30):
    try:
        self._auto_connect()
        _, _out, _err = self._client.exec_command(cmd)
        start_time = time.time()  # 1717034168
        while True:
            _temp_out = deepcopy(_out.read().decode())
            _temp_err = deepcopy(_err.read().decode())
            if not wait_for:
                break
            if wait_for in _temp_out or wait_for in _temp_err:
                raise AssertionError(f"can not found in output: {wait_for}")
            if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
                break
        return _temp_out  # if len(_err) == 0 else f"[err] {_err}"
    except Exception as e:
        error(f"command error as {e}")
        return None

2. lib/helm.py
from lib.ssh import SSH

class SSH_HELM:


def __init__(self, cfg: dict, verbose=True):
    self._cfg = {"host": cfg.get("host")}
    self._cfg["port"] = cfg.get("port", "22")
    self._cfg["username"] = cfg.get("username", "user")
    self._cfg["password"] = cfg.get("password", "1234")
    if not all(self._cfg.values()):
        raise ValueError(
            f"URL must include a value for the cfg={self._cfg} to use. None is not allowed!!"
        )
    debug(f"cfg error : {str(self._cfg)}")
    self._ssh = SSH(self._cfg)
    debug(f"cfg error22 :{str(self._ssh)}")
    info(f"init done [cfg={self._cfg}]" if verbose else "init done")



############# have some troubles at here #############
def command(self, cmd: str = None):
    # 1st
    self._ssh.connect()
    debug("connect 1st time - helm repo update")
    rr = self._ssh.command("/usr/sbin/helm repo update --debug | tee output1.json | cat")
    debug("connect 1st time - before disconnect")
    self._ssh.disconnect()
    debug(f"ssh helm information1 : {rr}")

    # 2nd
    self._ssh.connect()
    debug("connect 2nd time - helm repo update")        
    self._ssh.command("/usr/sbin/helm list -n default -o json > output.json 2> error.log")
    r = self._ssh.command("/usr/sbin/helm list -n default -o json --debug | tee output2.json | cat")  # connection ok. command nok.
    debug("connect 2nd time - before disconnect")
    self._ssh.disconnect()
    debug(f"ssh helm information2 : {r}")
    return json.loads(r)

3. remote server
~$ cat output.json
~$ cat output1.json
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "starlingx" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stx-platform" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "main-ran" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "rel-ran" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈
~$ cat output2.json
~$ cat error.log
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable
~$

4. local server's server.log
7474 INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
7475 INFO:root:[SSH] connected!
7476 DEBUG:root:[HELM] connect 1st time - helm repo update
7477 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
7478 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Received global request "hostkeys-00@openssh.com"
7479 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Rejecting "hostkeys-00@openssh.com" global request from server.
7480 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
7481 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
7482 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
7483 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
7484 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF sent (0)
7485 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
7486 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF received (0)
7487 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
7488 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 1 opened.
7489 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
7490 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] EOF received (1)
7491 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] EOF sent (1)
7492 DEBUG:root:[HELM] connect 1st time - before disconnect
7493 INFO:root:[SSH] disconnected!
7494 DEBUG:root:[HELM] ssh helm information1 : Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
7495 ...Successfully got an update from the "starlingx" chart repository
7496 ...Successfully got an update from the "stx-platform" chart repository
7497 ...Successfully got an update from the "main-ran" chart repository
7498 ...Successfully got an update from the "rel-ran" chart repository
7499 Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈
7500
7501 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xd7756910
7502 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_3.4.0
7503 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5
7504 INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_8.4p1)
7505 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange possibilities ===
7506 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos: curve25519-sha256, curve25519-sha256@libssh.org, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, ecdh-sha2-nistp384, ecdh-sha2-nistp521, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hell     man-group16-sha512, diffie-hellman-group18-sha512, diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
7507 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server key: rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ssh-ed25519
7508 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client encrypt: aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com, chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
7509 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server encrypt: aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com, chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
7510 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client mac: hmac-sha1, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-e     tm@openssh.com, umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com
7511 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server mac: hmac-sha1, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-e     tm@openssh.com, umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com
7512 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client compress: none
7513 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server compress: none
7514 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client lang: <none>
7515 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server lang: <none>
7516 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex follows: False
7517 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange agreements ===
7518 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
7519 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey: ssh-ed25519
7520 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher: aes128-ctr
7521 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC: hmac-sha2-256
7522 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression: none
7523 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== End of kex handshake ===
7524 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
7525 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to new keys ...
7526 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Got EXT_INFO: {'server-sig-algs': b'ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-n     istp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com'}
7527 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Adding ssh-ed25519 host key for [107.127.140.45]:22: b'3905a0de0b98965815ae8e152955952e'
7528 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is OK
7529 INFO:paramiko.transport:Auth banner:
7530 INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
7531 INFO:root:[SSH] connected!
7532 DEBUG:root:[HELM] connect 2nd time - helm repo update
7533 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
7534 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Received global request "hostkeys-00@openssh.com"
7535 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Rejecting "hostkeys-00@openssh.com" global request from server.
7536 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
7537 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
7538 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
7539 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF sent (0)
7540 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
7541 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF received (0)
7542 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
7543 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 1 opened.
7544 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
7545 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] EOF received (1)
7546 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] EOF sent (1)
7547 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 2] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
7548 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 2] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
7549 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 2 opened.
7550 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 2] Sesch channel 2 request ok
7551 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 2] EOF sent (2)
7552 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 3] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
7553 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 2] EOF received (2)
7554 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 3] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
7555 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 3 opened.
7556 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 3] Sesch channel 3 request ok
7557 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 3] EOF received (3)
7558 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 3] EOF sent (3)
7559 DEBUG:root:[HELM] connect 2nd time - before disconnect
7560 INFO:root:[SSH] disconnected!
7561 DEBUG:root:[HELM] ssh helm information2 :


